# URL Rewriting (Mod_Rewrite)

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I know absolutely nothing about mod_rewrite.
I'm asking how I could rewrite this URL as needed.

```
website.com?page=pagename&content=contents&action=download

as

website.com/pagename/contents/download
```

the param "action" will not always be set. Unsure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&content=$2&action=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]
```